# Can I use a Macbook (or an iMac) as a Bluetooth Player?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, imac, bluetooth

We all know that iPhone, iPod, and iPad cannot act as bluetooth players since they only have the hardware to act as a Bluetooth server. My question is if Macbook and iMac are similar.

If not, I like to set up a home network where multiple of my computers can play the same audio stream at the same time.

The reason that I do not use wireless audio system is because my apartment is jammed with wifi channels. There are around 200 wifi channels around me and wireless audio system doesn't work - same goes with airplay. I tried all the wireless system, only bluetooth works.

Comment: Are your computers connected to the network via wifi or ethernet?

Comment: You will end up with music playing not at the same time. I've tried such method but ended up using a double jack plug around the floor to get rid of this issue. Just my 2 cents..

Comment: Hi my computers are not connected to the internet. They are offline.

Comment: My apartment is too long to wire around audio cables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually cannot. Let me explain why:

1. The bluetooth hardware of Macbook and iMac are designed to be "sender" rather than "receiver"...
2. The software/driver is designed without considering using the computers as bluetooth receivers.

If you must connect two computers in an area where wifi channels are all taken, you can try using 5G wifi connection rather than the 2.4G - and if that still doesn't work, you are out of luck.

Note: wireless audio receivers usually are designed with special hardware component to eliminate lags - and even so there are so significant lags on all devices. So do not expect your computers will sync - in fact, there should be half or one second lag even in an ideal condition.

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I found a way to do this and thought I would share.  If you install Airserver on the iMac then you can "Airplay" the song to the iMac.  It's not exactly bluetooth, and it probably uses much more battery on the phone, but it allows you to play music from your phone through the iMac (or any computer for that matter.)  Just thought I would share.